# android ble cannot call onCharacteristicRead()

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm currently on a project developing an android app aiming to acquire data from wristbands and process them to get something like a health evaluation stuff. And I'm stuck on this problem that I cannot get the onCharacteristicRead() function to work... It just won't get called...

Here are the codes relative to this part:

```
private BluetoothGattCallback gattcallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, final int newState) {
        super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String status;
                switch (newState) {
                    case BluetoothGatt.STATE_CONNECTED:
                        lianjiezhuangtai.setText("connection succeed");
                        bluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(callback);
                        bluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
                        break;
                    case BluetoothGatt.STATE_CONNECTING:
                        lianjiezhuangtai.setText("trying to connect");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothGatt.STATE_DISCONNECTED:
                        lianjiezhuangtai.setText("connection lost");
                        break;
                    case BluetoothGatt.STATE_DISCONNECTING:
                        lianjiezhuangtai.setText("disconnecting");
                        break;
                }
                //pd.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        jibu.setText("run: trying to get steps");
        super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);

        if (status == bluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            final int sum = 100;//characteristic.getValue()[0];

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    jibu.setText("walked" + sum + "steps");
                }
            });

            Log.e(TAG, "onCharacteristicRead: " + characteristic.getValue()[0]);

        }

    }        
    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(final BluetoothGatt gatt,final int status) {
        super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
        Log.i(TAG, "run: trying to get steps");
        if (status == bluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            final List<BluetoothGattService> services = bluetoothGatt.getServices();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //List<String> serlist = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (final BluetoothGattService bluetoothGattService : services) {
                        bluetoothGattServices = bluetoothGattService;

                        Log.i(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered: " + bluetoothGattService.getUuid());

                        List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> charc = bluetoothGattService.getCharacteristics();

                        for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic charac : charc) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "run: " + charac.getUuid());
                            // 00002a06-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb 
                    //        bluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic_zd,true);
                            if (charac.getUuid().toString().equals("0000ff06-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")) {
                                characteristic_zd = charac;

                            } else if (charac.getUuid().toString().equals("00002a06-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")) {

                                characteristic_jb = charac;

                               // bluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic_jb,true);
                                bluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic_jb);
                                //sum = charac.getValue()[0];
                                gattcallback.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic_jb, status);
                                Log.i(TAG, "run: trying to get steps");
                            } else if (charac.getUuid().toString().equals("")) {
                            }
                        }


                        serviceslist.add(bluetoothGattService.getUuid().toString());

                    }
//                        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
//                                MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, serviceslist);
                    //list.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });
        }

    }



    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicWrite(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        super.onCharacteristicChanged(gatt, characteristic);



    }

};
```

So can anyone help me with this problem? Been searching for solutions for a while and still cannot solve this... Thanks a lot

Comment: I encountered the same problem when trying to read multiple gatt characteristics. Calling readCharacteristic in a for-loop didn't work for me either. The solution posted here helped me:
[Android how to read multiple BLE characteristics with a PriorityQueue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751152/android-how-to-read-multiple-ble-characteristics-with-a-priorityqueue#new-answer?newreg=d0b4e40db2044393a92d29bdbc202dfa)

Answer (score 1):

Three things:

1. You don't need to call super.method() in each callback.
2. You should not call onCharacteristicRead yourself, the Bluetooth stack will do that once a read response is retrieved after you have called the readCharacteristic method.
3. If there are more than one characteristic, your code won't work since Android's GATT api can only have one outstanding operation at a time. That means you need to wait for the onCharacteristicRead callback before you can do another readCharacteristic. (If you print the return value of readCharacteristic you will see that it prints true the first time but false the following times.)